# in Xcode project I get this linker command error with exit code 1

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I'm following this [example](https://github.com/adamhartford/SwiftR) about Swift + SignalR. This is all the installation steps:
[image]

I used another tutorial that helped me generate this pod file:

```
\# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'SwiftR iOS' do   # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks   use_frameworks!

  # Pods for SwiftR iOS

  target 'SwiftR iOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing   end

end

target 'SwiftR iOS Demo' do   # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks   # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for SwiftR iOS Demo

end

target 'SwiftR Mac' do   # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks   use_frameworks!

  # Pods for SwiftR Mac

  target 'SwiftR MacTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing   end

end

target 'SwiftR Mac Demo' do   # Comment this line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks   use_frameworks!

  # Pods for SwiftR Mac Demo

end
```

my Xcode project is closed and I tried to install it in Terminal:
pod install

It runs and says:

> Pod installation complete! There are 0 dependencies from the Podfile
>   and 0 total pods installed.

I can verify that all frameworks are not installed:
[image]

I still went to the Xcode project, set its deployment target to 9.0 and tried a build still and this is the error I get
[image]

I've already tried clean & restart and deleting the Xcode derived data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The owner of that tutorial answered my question:
If you're using this example for anything, I'm expecting you're up to date on .NET Core, DNX/DNU, donet cli, etc., etc. If you're not aware of recent .NET changes, be aware that the .NET Core stack is changing very rapidly these days and has not yet reached version 1.0. The SignalRDemo repository is a better starting point for the more familiar ASP.NET 4.5 stack.

Your description sounds like you're trying to use SwiftR, however. In that case, just clone the SwiftR repository, open SwiftR.xcodeproj, change the target to the iOS demo application, and the project will build/run in Xcode 7.

Answer (score 0):

Your podfile does not include any pods.

In between one of those `target TargetName do` and `end` lines you have to insert `pod SwiftR` so `pod install` installs the SwiftR pod and attaches it to that target. Depends on the name of the target you are actually using. You can see your targets in your Project settings in Xcode.

#### EDIT (to relfect comments)

The first time you run `pod install` (assuming there are pods to install) it will create a separate project file with the extension .xcworkspace. You must exit the xcodeproj if you have it open, and going forward only use the xcworkspace. It packages the pods and your main project files together in a single workspace so files compile correctly etc.

Comment: ok, I did add the pod SwiftR
and I ran it in the terminal and it says that it is successful. now instead of that pod file there is an entire pods xcode project. I open it in order to build and run it and nothing, I get a 'ding' in the mac as if I it is not supposed to build and run, now what!?
I just want to run the sample

Comment: @BhavukJain what!? Could you elaborate please!?

Comment: @user1019042 When you install pods, a new xcworkspace file is created. You need to use that instead of xcodproj.